# Name of this sorting algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

You have a shuffled set of cards. You have to re-order them.

You do this by assigning each card a number based on its value (jack = 11, queen - 12) etc and its suite (hearts = 0, clubs = 1 ...).  Each card gets unique number by formula (14 * suite) + value. You then have an empty array of 52 elements and just put each card in its correct position. This is very fast - big o would be O(N).  What is the name for this approach?

Answer (score 7):

It's called [Counting Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). You gain speed on expense of space.

Comment: Is it bucket sort ? Is it counting sort or something like this, OP simply puts elements to right position without comparing elements with each other.

Comment: @Anton You're totally right, thanks! My only excuse is that it's same family and counting sort is actually a trivial version of bucket sort...

Comment: Somewhat amusing how many upvotes this got while being wrong. :-)

Comment: @RandyHoward well, it wasn't completely wrong, see my previous comment :)

Comment: Yeah, it's probably splitting hairs at this point, unless it's for a homework assignment where he needs to be specific.

Comment: @icepack good point about the space. But what would you do to reduce space?

Comment: @MoreThanFive Nothing if you want to keep the speed as well. You have to pay for the operation somehow. Any general sorting algorithm based on comparisons is `Omega(nlogn)`. On many occasions computational algorithms time complexity can be reduced on expense of space complexity and vice versa - just like in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is no special name for it. It is a kind of [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) with unique identification of objects.

[Here is an overview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)